# Precisely position text in PowerPoint presentation

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint, openxml

[image]

I am writing a program, that uses OOXML SDK to generate a PPTX file. I need to accurately position text on the slide, but there is a problem with it. If I set text position to (0, 0), it looks as on the image. I have already set margins of text box to 0, but there is an other gap at the top of text box (see image). Decreasing height of the top box does not help , the "top gap" remains the same (see right part of image). The size of the gap is different for different font size.

How can I calculate distance between the top of text box and the top of the text (or baseline of text) if I know all font metrics?

Comment: Can you post some code you tried?

Comment: Text boxes have margins (top, bottom, left, right) that, if non-zero, hold the text away from the edges of the shape that contains the text.

Comment: When I saw the post and answered earlier, SO wasn't showing me your images for some reason. I see you've already dealt with margins.  From there it's a matter of line-spacing; if it's set to more than the point size of the text, there'll be extra room at top. Even if it's set to exactly the point size of the type, though, it still won't land exactly where you want it; each font has a certain amount of spacing built in so that when it's "set solid", ie multiple lines with no add'l spacing between them, it'll still have a modicum of spacing between lines. This is what you're seeing.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg
I made some investigation and it turned out that for any font of 100pt size - if linespace is changed from “single” to “exactly”, linespace size becomes of size 120pt . Is there some coefficient of 1.2 when changing linespace , or it depends on some other font metrics? Is there some way to calculate that “extra room at top” using font metrics or some other things. Maybe there is some coefficient known only by Microsoft or some known rules (that I don’t know)?

Comment: @Jeka  I don't have an answer for you, I'm afraid.  That extra 20% might be an arbitrary amount imposed by MS or it may just be a standard used by the type industry.  This page has a decent description of this ( look for "line gap") http://chanae.walon.org/pub/ttf/ttf_glyphs.htm